# Map image (x,y) to spherical coordinates

Tags: coordinates, image-processing

What is an efficient method to map image pixels (2D-Cartesian) to their spherical coordinates given camera azimuth and elevation?

(Ideally, response includes mathematical notation/Python/C++)

Comment: This is the wrong SE site for your question. You are likely to find some helpful information by reading answers in other SE sites, but I am not sure which ones. The simplest method would be to assume a pinhole camera geometry. See [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/28283/7982) and the references there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this isn't a complete answer but it may be of some help until you can find a better site for your question. See also [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/28283/7982) for more information.

Use a simple pinhole camera approximation where a ray that passes from the object through the center of the camera's pupil travels a straight line from object to the focal plane.

Assuming that the direction the camera is pointing is $\theta,\phi \ = 0, 0$ and the center of the film/focal plane is $x, y \ = \ 0,0$, then:

$$r =  f \tan(\theta);$$
$$x =  f \cos(\phi)\tan(\theta),$$
$$y =  f \sin(\phi)\tan(\theta).$$

Run that backwards and you get

$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2};$$
$$\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{r}{f} \right),$$
$$\phi = \arctan2(y, x).$$

The math gets much more complicated if:

1. The camera has a lot of distortion (e.g. a fisheye lens)
2. You want a spherical coordinate system who's "north pole" ($\theta = 0$) is in some other direction than where you are pointing your camera.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for using the wrong SE. If you could list more detailed models to look further into, that would be fantastic.

Comment: @JeffreyWardman I would propose the following. 1) Search [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) and [Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) (and any others you can think of) for the closes question you can find to yours *that has an answer* 2) write a new question for that site linking to that question or an answer there, and explain how your question is related but different, 3) say a bit more about the orientation of the coordinate system you want to use, and 4)...

Comment: @JeffreyWardman ...4) add a link to some reading that you have done so far explain where you are stuck. That would be the most effective way to proceed, and is more Stack Exchange friendly than "I'm want to do X please give me links and software".

Comment: thanks for your help. Very much appreciated.